# Node.js proxy to return exact response from the external website

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create the express.js proxy to an external website to obtaining audio data from there. I know about modules like `http-proxy`, but think they are excessive for the case when only one url-bound request goes through proxy. I'm using the code below:

```
express.get('/proxy', function (req, res) {

    var options ={
        host: "website.com",
        port: 80,
        path: "/audio/test.mp3",
        method: 'GET'
    };

    http.get(options, function (audioRes) {
        var data = [], dataLen = 0;

        audioRes.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data.push(chunk);
            dataLen += chunk.length;
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            var buf = new Buffer(dataLen);
            res.set(audioRes.headers);
            res.send(buf);
        });
    })
    .on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    });

});
```

I get response, but it cannot be decoded as a valid audio. While debugging with the Fiddler, I found out that the number of bites sent by a server mismatches the number specified in the `Content-Length` header (which indicates fewer bytes being retrieved).

I cannot figure out how to properly return the exact response that's been retrieved from the remote server. Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Try this code example: http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/ It forgoes buffering output altogether, making it more efficient. In any case your code is wrong because you never put any data into the `buf` buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send request via proxy, you can set the proxy url in `Host` header. Also you have to specify the full URL of the external resource you are trying to access via proxy.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: "proxy",
  port: 8080,
  path: "http://www.google.com",  //full URL
  headers: {
    Host: "10.1.2.3"              //your proxy location
  }
};
http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

I am not sure why it is not returning full response. Can you post your options.

#### Update

Try this inside `/proxy` after putting the options

```
http.get(options, function (audioRes) {
    audioRes.pipe(res);
})
.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: I've probably failed to clearly explain what the problem is. I'm not sending request through the proxy, I want my nodejs app act like one. I want to get the parameters of the user's request to my site, build another request to the external resource based on these params, and then return the received response from that resource to the end user. Added options object into original question.

Comment: I have added the part you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, that does work! It's worth pointing out though that I had to set proper `Content-Type` header before piping, otherwise it simply got downloaded instead of streaming to the audio control.